# Browser Link connection is shown as "Unknown"

Tags: visual-studio-2017, browser-link

I'm using browser link, plus [Browser Link Inspector 2017](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.BrowserLinkInspector2017)

When loading my website, which is running in IIS, the `Browser Link Dashboard` shows zero connections to my web project, but 1 connection title "Unknown"

[image]

I have no idea what the problem is here.

Since the connection is unknown, none of the browser link inspector features work. When I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> I see the browser window dim, and a cross appear, but selecting elements on the page does nothing.

Can someone help me out please? How can I stop the connection being "unknown"?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue, for me it was caused because my solution has 2 projects and both has same ID.

Editing the `.sln` file I found that both projects has the same ID, so I changed one of them and it works. !

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.27004.2010
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "HTI Model", "HTI Model\HTI Model.csproj", "{CF209992-A8B0-44E8-8E02-6AFDFADADDCA}"
EndProject
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "HTI", "HTI\HTI.csproj", "{3CE82B75-A87A-4A5B-B9A0-AF481A815359}"
EndProject
```

note that `9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556` is repeated in both project so I changed the second to a random one `FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC`

I also changed the order putting the main project at the top an the Model project at bottom.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 15
VisualStudioVersion = 15.0.27004.2010
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{9A19103F-16F7-4668-BE54-9A1E7A4F7556}") = "HTI", "HTI\HTI.csproj", "{3CE82B75-A87A-4A5B-B9A0-AF481A815359}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "HTI Model", "HTI Model\HTI Model.csproj", "{CF209992-A8B0-44E8-8E02-6AFDFADADDCA}"
EndProject
```

It solved for me !

Comment: Wow, that's a great find! I'll have to revisit this for myself and see if this is the same problem in my solution. Great job!